# Combining two javascript functions to calculate form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that calculates the time between two dates, and stores 6 numeric fields.

I wnat to be ale to have the form claculate these values as the user starts selecting after the two dates so that the form works as intended.

A sample page is located here..of what my intentions are

http://jsfiddle.net/GfN5u/1/ the js is withing the html

I feel i'm almost there but lifes not fair to me this week.

Also in IE 8 the select elements lose their content.....even in jsfiddle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

```
        <script>
        var txt1 = document.Edit.StartTime.value
        var txt2 = document.Edit.EndTime.value

        var differenceInSeconds = (Calendar.parseDate(txt2, false).getTime() - Calendar.parseDate(txt1, false).getTime())/1000;
        var val9 = differenceInSeconds/60.0/60
        alert(val9)
        </script>


            <script>
        re=/\D/g

        function getGoodVal(fld) {
        var val = fld.value;
        if (!val) val=0;
        if (isNaN(val)) {
        val=val.replace(re,""); // remove all nonDigits
        }
        if (val=="" || isNaN(val)) val = 0; // still not a number or empty
        val = parseFloat(val)
        fld.value=val.toFixed(2);
        return val;
        }

        function calc(theForm) {
        var val10 = val9
        var valb = getGoodVal(theForm.lunch);   
        var val1 = getGoodVal(theForm.TRDO);
        var val2 = getGoodVal(theForm.AnnualLeave);
        var val3 = getGoodVal(theForm.PersonalLeave);
        var val4 = getGoodVal(theForm.WorkFromHome);
        var val5 = getGoodVal(theForm.TOIL); 

        total = (val9-valb) + (val1+val2+val3+val4+val5);
        theForm.total.value=total.toFixed(2)
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: The code in that fiddle is horrid. Is it auto generated? You also forgot to mention your using some obscure calendar control and what is `document.Edit` ?

Comment: @Raynos, while I can't disagree with the content of your comment, I think it isn't very helpful in assisting webb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the values as the user selects dates, link your calculation to some javascript event that is called after a date is selected. I noticed that you attempted to link your calc() function to the onChange event of the text inputs, which does not work. You can link the calc() function to the onSelect property of Calendar.setup. It will look something like this:

```
  Calendar.setup({
    inputField : "StartTime",
    trigger    : "f_btn1",
    onSelect   : function() { this.hide(); calc(document.forms[0]); },
    showTime   : 12,
    dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"
  });
```

Notice that calc() is called just like the onChange property of the input element. However, the reference to the form changes because the form is not part of the Calendar scope: document.forms[0].

It would probably be helpful to your users to have a function that verifies that updates the end time so that it cannot be earlier than the start time.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, would you be kind enough to assist in getting it to work. I can do this in code but not in js so my dilemma grows bigger. Thanks

Comment: That works fabulously. I can't thank you enough. If i may just ask one more silly question it doesn't work in IE 8

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a copy of IE8 to test it with. It may be a good idea to not run any of the Calendar.Setup(...) calls until the page loads. I'm not tremendously familiar with MooTools so can't give you exact info now. Look for something like document.ready() and put the Calendar.Setup calls in there.

Comment: found the error,it was the fld.value=val.toFixed(2); . Thanks for all your help